# migrate clawsmail from windows to linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, email

I'm moving from Windows 7 to Linux, and I need a way to migrate my existing clawsmail settings and mail from Windows to Linux.  What would the process be?  Can I just copy the mail directories and config files to the correct locations in linux after installing clawsmail on linux? If so, what would the correct locations on linux be? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?